# How can I find/collect license information for our cookbook dependencies in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, licensing

We use Chef `12.x-16.x`. Is there a simple way to collect license information for all the packages we dependent on (directly and indirectly)? We get all our dependencies from Supermarket.

In the `npm` world, we use `license-checker`. Any recommendations on similar tools for Chef?

Answer (score 1):

i assume you are leveraging [berkshelf](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf) to manager your cookbook dependencies.

```sh
COOKBOOKS=$(bundle exec berks list --format json | jq -r '.cookbooks[].name')
for cookbook in $COOKBOOKS
do
  bundle exec berks info $cookbook
done
```

depending on your environment setup, you might not need to use `bundle exec`